# How do I get results from a multiple drop down menu?

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu, resultset

To reduce the risk of sql injection I decided only to use preset drop down menus for users to query the database. I have a set of five drop downs that work well together with a single submit button and it opens the page it should but I'm not getting any data. I think I've tried everything that I can find and I suspect it is the select line that is wrong but I've tried dozens of variations without success. It seems that every tutorial shows something different and none of the ones I've found have helped.
The drop down I'm using is this:

```
<form action="test_result3.php" method="post">

    <?php

mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password');
mysql_select_db('database');



    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT Country FROM engravers Where Country <>'' AND Country IS NOT NULL ORDER by Country";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    echo "<select name\\='Country'>";
    echo "<option value='$_POST'>Country</option>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['Country'] . "'>" . $row['Country'] . "</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";

    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT Year FROM engravers Where Year <>'' AND Year IS NOT NULL ORDER by Year";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    echo "<select name\\='Year'>";
    echo "<option value='$_POST'>Year</option>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['Year'] . "'>" . $row['Year'] . "</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";

    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT Engraver1Surname FROM engravers Where Engraver1Surname <> '' AND Engraver1Surname IS NOT NULL ORDER by Engraver1Surname";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

      echo "<select name\\='Engraver1Surname'>";
      echo "<option value='$_POST'>Engraver</option>";
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo "<option value='" . $row['Engraver1Surname'] . "'>" . $row['Engraver1Surname'] . "</option>";
      }
      echo "</select>";

      $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT Designer1Surname FROM engravers Where Designer1Surname <>'' AND Designer1Surname IS NOT NULL ORDER by Designer1Surname";
      $result = mysql_query($sql);

      echo "<select name\\='Designer1Surname'>";
      echo "<option value='$_POST'>Designer</option>";
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo "<option value='" . $row['Designer1Surname'] . "'>" . $row['Designer1Surname'] . "</option>";
      }
      echo "</select>";

     $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT Printer FROM engravers Where Printer <>'' AND Printer IS NOT NULL ORDER by Printer";
      $result = mysql_query($sql);

      echo "<select name\\='Printer'>";
      echo "<option value='$_POST'>Printer</option>";
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo "<option value='" . $row['Printer'] . "'>" . $row['Printer'] . "</option>";
      }
      echo "</select>";

          ?>

            <input type="submit" />   
        </form>
```

This takes me to the php page test_results3 but it is blank.

```
<?php

 mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password') or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error()); 


 $query=("SELECT * FROM engravers WHERE $Country = $_POST['Country']", $Year = $_POST['Year'], $Engraver1Surname = $_POST['Engraver1Surname'], $Designer1Surname = $_POST['Designer1Surname]', $Printer = $_POST['Printer']);

while($result = mysql_fetch_array( $query ));

$num=mysql_numrows($result);
$i=0;
while ($i,$num){
$i++;
}

{ 
echo   $result['Country']; 
echo " "; 
echo  $result['Year']; 
echo "  Engraver: "; 
echo  $result['Engraver1Surname']; 
echo "  Designer: "; 
echo  $result['Designer1Surname']; 
echo "  Printer: "; 
echo  $result['Printer']; 
echo " "; 
$img_url = "http://www.engravedstamps.net/images/"; 
   { 
    echo '<img src="'.$img_url.$result['Images'].'" />'; 
   } 

   echo "<br>"; 

   echo "<br>"; 
   } 

$anymatches=mysql_num_rows($data); 
if ($anymatches == 0) 
{ 
echo "Sorry, but we can not find an entry to match your query<br><br>"; 
} 

echo "<b>Searched For:</b> " .$find; 
} 
mysql_close();
?>
    I seem to be getting more confused and frustrated by the hour with this. So far I've spent six weeks trying to write a three page search and display website and I don't feel like I'm any closer than when I started. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.
```

Comment: `To reduce the risk of sql injection I decided only to use preset drop down menus for users to query the database` values can be easily edited in Firebug. Just start using prepared statements

Comment: Thanks turson, I didn't know that. Reading up on prepared statements seems like a good idea. Now to find a manual on them that is easier to understand than php.net.

Comment: Personally I recommend PDO. Good luck!